# Copy text in GTK TextView

Tags: textview, gtk

In TextView there are words painted in different colors. The problem is that if I copy words within a given TextView, the colors remain, but if I copy to another TextView, they disappear.

Comment: could you share a sample working code for this.. from your statement I believe that in the second TextView CSS has not been applied that's why the colours are disappearing?.

Comment: Working code https://docs.google.com/document/d/1g1b0evAkqsxuBiQlzT7Zz5qzN147NpJPo4nRFFu5fG8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

So in textView-1 you are applying the buffer with tags (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html) tags are like properties with which the text is applied in the View. Even when you try to write something in your textView-1 without applying buffer tags that text will appear to be normal.

When copying you are just copying the text as a string without the properties so while inserting you have to insert the text along with the tags to change their color.

If the color is constant(same color in a textview) in the textview's then you could change the textview css.

```
textview text {
color : #4fc3f7;
}
```

this would change the text color to blue.

Comment: I programmatically change the color of several words, that is, one word has color1, the other has color2 and then I need to copy manually (Copy/Paste) all the words to another TextView. In Qt TextEdit it works

Comment: in Gtk when you copy the text inside the same editor it will work.. I dont think it's possible when copying to a different text editor.If you have the QT code could you share it i could try to analyze and see how it works and check the possibilities in gtk

Comment: In Qt, you need to run the example Qt\Examples\Qt-5.11.2\widgets\richtext\textedit\textedit.pro. 
Run 2 instances of the application and do Copy/Paste. I hope that the developers of the GTK will someday finalize TextView similarly